# How to download a file that gets processed over an HTTP request in Java?

Tags: java, http, get, request, tex

I'm writing a program that builds stuff in a GUI (blah blah blah... irrelevant details), and the user is allowed to export that data as a .tex file which can be compiled to a PDF. Since I don't really want to assume they have a TeX environment installed, I'm using an API (latexonline.cc). That way, I can construct an HTTP GET request, send it to the API, then (hopefully!) return the PDF in a byte-stream. The issue, though, is that when I submit the request, I'm only getting the page data back from the request instead of the data from the PDF. I'm not sure if it's because of how I'm doing my request or not...

Here's the code:

```
... // preceding code
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("test.pdf"));
StringBuilder httpTex = new StringBuilder();
httpTex.append(this.getTexCode(...)); // This appends the TeX code (nothing wrong here)

// Build the URL and HTTP request.
String texURL = "https://latexonline.cc/compile?text=";
String paramURL = URLEncoder.encode(httpTex.toString(), "UTF-8");

URL url = new URL(texURL + paramURL);
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
try {
    InputStream is = url.openStream();
    int bufferLen = -1;
    while ((bufferLen = is.read(buffer)) > -1) {
        this.getOutputStream().write(buffer, 0, bufferLen);
    }

    dos.close();
    is.close();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Edit: Here's the data I'm getting from the GET request:
https://pastebin.com/qYtGXUsd

Comment: You are asking us why `latexonline.cc` behaves the way it does. We do not know that. What is "the page data" that is returned to you?

Comment: The data that's returned is the actual HTML/CSS/JS that makes up the "download" page.

Comment: "The service will return HTTP.2xx on success and compiled PDF file. Otherwise a HTTP.4xx code will be returned with a compilation error log in response body."

Comment: Note that [Files.copy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.CopyOption...)) is generally a better way to save an InputStream to a file, as it narrows down the possibility for errors.  But in this case, I don’t think that’s the problem;  consider editing your question and showing us the unexpected HTML content you are receiving.

Comment: @VGR Yeah, that wasn't the issue. I tried it. And I added the unexpected HTML (like I said, it's literally just the page data from the download.

Comment: Please put the HTML into your question as a text block.  That pastebin entry won’t be around forever, and without that information, your question won’t be of much value to future readers.  That aside, the HTML says “LatexOnline is compiling...” at the end, so apparently you cannot use this site non-interactively.  I assume some JavaScript in the page uses an additional connection to an internal service, and redirects you to the finished PDF when it’s ready.  Java SE has no support for that.

Comment: You are sending your request OK. The problem is that you are trying to use as an remote API an application which is actually oriented to a web browser, because it contains important parts in javascript code.

Comment: So there's NO way to do this? That really sucks... it looks like the page is redirecting me no matter what I try to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! I used a different API and it works perfectly.

https://github.com/YtoTech/latex-on-http